# Post Method value is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

The return of email2 is undefined. The method userRepository.getAllConfirmedEmails(...) delivers the right value, but in the post methode the return is undefinded.

```
  app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
        const { email } = req.body;
    
        // get safetyAttribues
        const safetyAttributes = await safetyAttributesClass.getSafetyAttributes(email);
    
        // if both are true, try to send login challenge
        if (safetyAttributes.isAccepted && safetyAttributes.isConfirmed) {
            if (safetyAttributes.isAdmin) {
                const email2;
                 const token = await safetyAttributesClass.generateAdminToken(email).then(async (token)  => {
                     email2 = await userRepository.getAllConfirmedEmails(email, token).then(async (email2) => {
                        console.log("HIER STEHT DIE ZWEITE EMAIL-->" , email2);
                     })
                     
                });
                
                
    
            }
            const user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
            console.log('HIER ISTHEH <USJR', user);
            if (!user) {
                return res.sendStatus(400);
            }
    
            const assertionChallenge = generateLoginChallenge(user.key);
            userRepository.updateUserChallenge(user, assertionChallenge.challenge);
    
            res.send(assertionChallenge);
        }
        // if not, send attributes to frontend to handle client-side
        else {
            res.send({ isAcceptet: safetyAttributes.isAccepted, isConfiremd: safetyAttributes.isConfirmed })
        }
    
    });
```

Comment: you shouldnt declare a const variable without assigning it a value

Comment: Thanks, but with var it also not working...

Comment: In addition to not using `const` but `let`, you would need to `return email2` inside your `then`. Right now, it's just doing `console.log` and not returning anything. But follow @sp00m's advice

Comment: can you show `userRepository.getAllConfirmedEmails` this function?

Answer (score 1):

You're oddly mixing async/await with #then, probably sticking with async/await will help:

```js
const token = await safetyAttributesClass.generateAdminToken(email);
const email2 = await userRepository.getAllConfirmedEmails(email, token);
console.log("HIER STEHT DIE ZWEITE EMAIL-->", email2);
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunatelly HIER STEHT DIE ZWEITE EMAIL--> [] it is also empty... :(((

Comment: That means this piece of code works ;) If you're not expecting this returned value, you must have an issue in the implementation of userRepository#getAllConfirmedEmails; try to debug it to see what values are passed in and which code path they follow.

Comment: But the serRepository.getAllConfirmedEmails(email, token) is returning the right value. Before I'm returnig the value I checked with console.log

Comment: Hmm, without the code, I won't be able to help much I'm afraid, but here are some debugging tracks: 1) You did not log the right value; 2) You did not log right before the return, and something modified the value before being returned; 3) The userRepository you're using isn't imported from the right file; 4) [~select is indeed broken~](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should return email2 in your getAllConfirmedEmails callback. Like so

```
    app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
            const { email } = req.body;
        
            // get safetyAttribues
            const safetyAttributes = await safetyAttributesClass.getSafetyAttributes(email);
        
            // if both are true, try to send login challenge
            if (safetyAttributes.isAccepted && safetyAttributes.isConfirmed) {
                if (safetyAttributes.isAdmin) {
                    const email2;
                     const token = await safetyAttributesClass.generateAdminToken(email).then(async (token)  => {
                         email2 = await userRepository.getAllConfirmedEmails(email, token)
                         
                    });
                    
                    
        
                }
                const user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
                console.log('HIER ISTHEH <USJR', user);
                if (!user) {
                    return res.sendStatus(400);
                }
        
                const assertionChallenge = generateLoginChallenge(user.key);
                userRepository.updateUserChallenge(user, assertionChallenge.challenge);
        
                res.send(assertionChallenge);
            }
            // if not, send attributes to frontend to handle client-side
            else {
                res.send({ isAcceptet: safetyAttributes.isAccepted, isConfiremd: safetyAttributes.isConfirmed })
            }
        
        })

;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! but unfortunatelly HIER STEHT DIE ZWEITE EMAIL--> [] it is also empty... :(((

Comment: what is `getAllConfirmedEmails` returning ?

Comment: I am wondering if `getAllConfirmedEmails` returns email2 then, this should be enough:
`email2 = await userRepository.getAllConfirmedEmails(email, token)`